# Newby setting up a small business with an IP Credit card machine

Tags: vlan, vpn

I have a small network with a shared internet connection.  I have a router separating my network and everything into an unmanaged switch.  The credit card machine security ran a check and said we are too vulnerable.

So I put the CC machine directly to a physical port on the router next to the the switch uplink port on the router.  I also created a tagged VLAN for the CC machine and statically assigned it outside the DHCP range for the network switch thinking it was isolated now.

So they ran another check and it is still wide open.  What can I do to make sure that the CC machine is secure from our network and attacks from the internet?  VPN, subnet, etc...

Comment: This question is too broad. We need a good description or diagram of the network, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Speculation and guessing are off-topic here.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing basic security devices like a firewall. You’ll probably need one to be compliant.

Comment: I think you should consider hiring someone to give you a hand.

Comment: You're entering a realm of substantial legal liability. So hire a professional that knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ron has pointed out,The question is broad and you have not shared any specific model number and Diagram..

I'm  going to assume that you don't have a firewall attached in the system configuration.

The below mentioned are few options you can consider to verify the vulnerability and mitigate the same.

1. If your router is having openWRT/DDWRT OS,Then the router itself will give decent protection against common vulnerabilities.Set the Firewall to high from the GUI.
2. Buy a decent firewall and then connect the same between your CPE/ONT and Router. Identify the policies and rules you would need and update the ACL on the same.
3. Once the configuration is set then spin up a Kali Linux live boot on your laptop and then trigger NMAP port scans and vulnerability scans against your WAN IP and Router's interface. If not Kali Linux,atleast download the nmap/zenmap and run a port scan.Read the help,you will get the basic idea.

You can also try asking the Security guy about the identified vulnerabilities and then make a tailor fit mitigation plan against the same too.

Comment: Based on the comments it looks like I will be hiring a security guy to set this up.  It is a TPLink VPN router with a firewall.  I thought that would be enough.  Apparently there are too far many tailored settings for a Newby to handle.

Comment: Good,If you find the answer helpful then please accept it.